# Errors building ios project with CMake

Tags: ios, xcode, build, cmake

I'm trying to build an ios app using CMake, and I am running into a few warnings and errors.  First, I'm getting this when I call cmake:

```
CMake Error in CMakeLists.txt:


    Syntax error in cmake code when parsing string

            <string>arxan.${PRODUCT_NAME:rfc1034identifier}</string>

      syntax error, unexpected cal_SYMBOL, expecting } (48)
```

It still seems to build everything though, and I can run make.  However, I get the following warning:

```
clang: warning: no such sysroot directory: 'iphoneos'
```

and error:

```
In file included from /Users/aottinger/TestFrameWorkiOS/AppDelegate.m:9:
/Users/aottinger/TestFrameWorkiOS/AppDelegate.h:9:9: fatal error: 
      'UIKit/UIKit.h' file not found
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
```

Here is my CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)
project(auto_generated_xcodeproj)
set(NAME auto_generated_xcodeproj)

file(GLOB headers *.h)
file(GLOB sources *.c *.cpp *.cc *.m)

set(CMAKE_OSX_SYSROOT iphoneos7.1)
set(CMAKE_OSX_ARCHITECTURES "arm64")
set(CMAKE_XCODE_EFFECTIVE_PLATFORMS "-iphoneos")

add_executable(${NAME} MACOSX_BUNDLE ${APP_TYPE} ${headers} ${sources})
target_link_libraries(${NAME} 
    "-framework Foundation" 
    "-framework CoreGraphics"
    "-framework UIKit"
    "-framework XCTest")

set_target_properties(${NAME} PROPERTIES
    MACOSX_BUNDLE_GUI_IDENTIFIER "com.arxan.auto_generated_xcodeproj"
    MACOSX_BUNDLE_INFO_PLIST ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/Info.plist
    XCODE_ATTRIBUTE_DEBUG_INFORMATION_FORMAT "dwarf-with-dysm"
    XCODE_ATTRIBUTE_GCC_PRECOMPILE_PREFIX_HEADER YES
    XCODE_ATTRIBUTE_GCC_PREFIX_HEADER ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/Prefix.pch
    XCODE_ATTRIBUTE_INFOPLIST_PREPROCESS YES
    XCODE_ATTRIBUTE_IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET 7.1)
```

I don't understand why it can't find the header file as I linked the frameworks, and I'm at a loss for the other CMake error and clang warning.

Comment: It's not a valid cmake variable `${PRODUCT_NAME:rfc1034identifier}`. Here is a project that must work fine: https://github.com/forexample/testapp

Comment: `file(GLOB headers *.h)` and don't use GLOB))

Comment: Thanks, I looked at your CMakeLists.txt and made a few changes, and everything seems to build fine now.  However, this pops up when I try to run the app on a connected device from Xcode: The application at /Users/aottinger/autoGenAppTest/Debug-iphoneos/test_ios.app does not specify a CFBundleExecutable

Comment: Does this error occur while building my project?

Comment: Your project won't build at all:  build.sh: line 7:  3087 Segmentation fault: 11  cmake -H. -B_builds -GXcode

Comment: I ran it without -GXcode and this is where it is failing:                CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:15 (sugar_fatal_error):
  Unknown CMake command "sugar_fatal_error".

Comment: `CMake command sugar_fatal_error` copy/paste from my other project)) I've updated, try to pull new commit. It's simply `message(FATAL_ERROR ...)`. This project only works for Xcode generator

Comment: It's still failing, and it fails because of the -GXcode flag

Comment: Do you have an xcode installed? It's kind of mandatory for iOS projects))

Comment: Yea, in fact I have two different versions, but the older one is on my Desktop, so it should be out of the way.  I can build my app now, it just won't run for the reason mentioned above

Comment: I figured it out.  I looked at your Info.in file and changed a few things in mine accordingly

Comment: Script `build.sh` works fine, take a look at Travis CI log: https://travis-ci.org/forexample/testapp/builds/29531859